# Format TextField text during tapping

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to format my text in swiftui in a TextField, to add some space like that :

when text changed :
191064221849132
to have 1 91 06 42 218 491 32

I tried with some @state and @Binding, but nothing really work.

Comment: Please share the actual code that you tried and what exactly didn't work. Is the pattern always the same?

Comment: it's not about the patern it's about the way to do that. I have the paterne and solution. But I don't know how to replace my text with the new formatted one in my textfield the user is tapping.

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I just want to replace formatted text in the TextField. I have the solution to change my String. I just d'ont know how to change it when user is tapping

Comment: Maybe you can do this with a tap gesture: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/adding_interactivity_with_gestures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to use a custom `Formatter` or the `onCommit` handler.  Annoyingly these are not applied as you type, but only when you commit editing

`Formatter` example:

```
final class CapitalizedFormatter: Formatter {
  override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
    guard let string = obj as? String else {
      return ""
    }
    return string.uppercased()
  }

  override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    obj?.pointee = string as NSString
    return true
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var capitalizedText: String = ""
  var body: some View {
    TextField(
      "placeholder",
      value: $capitalizedText,
      formatter: CapitalizedFormatter()
    )
  }
}
```

`onCommit` example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var capitalizedText: String = ""
  var body: some View {
    TextField(
      "Placeholder",
      text: $capitalizedText,
      onCommit: { self.capitalizedText = self.capitalizedText.uppercased() }
    )
  }
}
```

If you want continuous text values then use a binding to intercept the new values in the setter, then format them, then emit the value in the getter:

```
final class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var capitalizedText = ""
  func set(text: String) {
    capitalizedText = text.uppercased()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: Model
  var textBinding: Binding<String>
  init() {
    let model = Model()
    self.textBinding = .init(
      get: { model.capitalizedText },
      set: { model.set(text: $0) }
    )
    self.model = model
  }

  var body: some View {
    TextField(
      "Placeholder",
      text: textBinding
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: returning an empty string instead of nil doesn't make any sense `{ (obj as? String)?.uppercased() }`

Comment: Note: Not related to the original question but you've named your class capitalized  but you are actually uppercasing all letters. Your method `string(for obj)` should return `(obj as? String)?.capitalized`

Comment: It was the way to achieve it. This solution work perfectly. Just another problem, cursor don't move to the end when text is modified from the observed object.

Comment: @theMouk make a new question